# Angular 6: Changing the code of an external library only works with 'ng serve' and not with 'ng build'

Tags: angular, npm, libraries

I'm working on a project where I have installed an external library for it. The [ng-select library by Bas van den Berg](https://github.com/basvandenberg/ng-select), which works pretty great but need the library to work with onPush change detection strategy. I needed to add a ChangeDetectorRef hence I can use markForCheck().

So I figured that I would go to the ng-select.es5.js file and just import the ChangeDetectorRef from the @angular/core, define and initialize the changeDetectorRef and use markForCheck() where needed, like this:

```
import { Component, ContentChild, ElementRef, EventEmitter, HostListener, Input, NgModule, Output, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation, forwardRef, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

...

```
var SelectComponent = /** @class */ (function () {
/**
 * @param {?} hostElement
 * @param {?} changeDetectorRef
 */
function SelectComponent(hostElement, changeDetectorRef) {
    this.hostElement = hostElement;
    this.changeDetectorRef = changeDetectorRef;
    console.log('constructor', this.changeDetectorRef, changeDetectorRef, ChangeDetectorRef);
```

...

```
SelectComponent.ctorParameters = function () {
    return [
        { type: ElementRef, },
        { type: ChangeDetectorRef, }
    ];
};
```

...

```
    SelectComponent.prototype.updateState = function (functionName) {
    console.log(functionName)
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        _this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
    });
};
```

Now when I do a 'ng serve' in the project I can see that the markForCheck() get executed correctly, but if i do an 'ng build --aot' or 'ng build --prod' I get this error message:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'markForCheck' of undefined

So after some debugging, I tried logging this.changeDetectorRef in the constructor. Locally with 'ng serve it just logs the correct stuff but in 'ng build' it logs an undefined.

How is that possible? Is there a difference in compiling between 'ng serve' and 'ng build'? Do I need to put this code somewhere else or something?

Edit: As you can see there is also an ElementRef called hostElement which does work, and is completely defined and initialized the same as the changeDetectorRef.

Edit2: Okay, i tried it again without --aot or --prod and then i don't have the error. but i need it to work with --prod. how can i make this happen? So the better question would be: Whats the difference between regular 'ng build' and 'ng build --prod'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i finally found what was going on.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11262#issuecomment-244472000

Apparently you need to add the library your using in a '*.metadata.json' file.